# Difference between $[a,b]\in \mathbb R$ and $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory, notation

What is the difference between the following?

Are they both mathematically correct?

\begin{align}
[a,b]\in \mathbb R \tag 1 \\
[a,b]\subset \mathbb R \tag 2
\end{align}

And also, which one should I use If I want to say "the interval between $a$ and $b$ is real"? Feel free to correct me if this phrasing is inaccurate.

Comment: $\in$ is for elements and $\subset$ is for sets. The first would be valid only if $[a,b]$ were a real number.

Comment: As has already been explained, (1) is incorrect while (2) is correct. This misconception may have come from the fact both elements and subsets of $\Bbb R$ are sometimes described as "in" $\Bbb R$. We sometimes say for clarity that $\Bbb R$ *contains* or *includes* its subsets, and *owns* its elements. In other words, (1) is wrong because it claims ownership rather than inclusion.

Comment: @J.G. I don't think I've ever heard "owns" used in that context in English. (On the other hand the Danish pronunciation of $\in$ literally means "is owned by", so I agree that metaphor is not crazy -- just that it doesn't seem to be common in English).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Also, $x\in y$ can be rewritten as $y\owns x$; $\owns$ comes from the LaTeX `\owns`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $[a,b]$ is a set then only second is validate:

$$ [a,b] := \{x\in \mathbb{R}; a\leq x\leq b\} \implies [a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$$

If the question was, is $[a,b]\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ (that is the power set of $\mathbb{R}$) then the answer would be yes.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that $a$ and be are real numbers and that $a\leqslant b$, then the assertion $[a,b]\in\mathbb R$ is false, since it means that the interval $[a,b]$ is an *element* of $\mathbb R$. If you want to assert that $[a,b]$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, you write $[a,b]\subset\mathbb R$.